# using specific bootstrap columns in django template based on the numbers of models

Tags: django, django-models, bootstrap-4, django-templates, django-views

i have created a search result page which results 3 different models. For the results i need to use bootstrap columns. so what i need to do is display them with bootstrap columns.and there's a condition that if there is only one search result i need to use col-12 and if two col-6 and if three col-4 
can anyone provide me a demo code?

```
enter code here
 {% if jud %}
         <h2>Search results:</h2>
         <div class="row">
            {% for product in products %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                   <h4>{{ product.title }}</h4>
                   <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
                   <h6 class="btn btn-primary btn-large">More info</h6>
               </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
       {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this inside row div.

`<div class="col"></div>`

How it works: If you don't specify the number of columns, all columns in the row take up the same amount of space.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom template tag.
Something like this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def column_width(products):
    width = {1: 12, 2: 6, 3: 4}
    return width[len(products)]
```

And in template:

```
{% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-md-{% column_width products %}">
            <div class="jumbotron">
               <h4>{{ product.title }}</h4>
               <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
               <h6 class="btn btn-primary btn-large">More info</h6>
           </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: your answer worked for  {% for product in products %}
but what should i do for {% for cate in category %}

Comment: how do i use count instead of len

Comment: your concept worked for me but the calculation you made 
width = {1: 12, 2:6, 3:4} is not an answer what i wanted.

Comment: i have an app named sales so in sales.models i have three classes electronicDevices, HomeAppliances, MusicalInstruments  so when i make search i need to display them with the respective bootstrap columns.
if there is a result for electronicdevice only i need to display it in col-12 
and if there is result for electronicdevice and musicalinstrument but not homeappliance or for musicalinstrument and homeappliance bot not electronic device i need col-6 and if all display in col-4 
your ans of using custom template tag worked but was working according to the no. of results present